# Data fetching from API issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-frontend, weather-api

I am at beginner level of React framework and am creating a weather app. So I fetch the data from the API and pass the object as a value to a parameter in my component. Now when trying to access the inner data values of the object, I am facing an error.

So I took the parameter as
in App.js

```
{weather && <WeatherDisp data = {weather}/>}
```

in WeatherDisp.js

```
const WeatherDisp = ({data}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{data.main.temp}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

on writing this I am getting the error as :

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')

Can anyone help?

Comment: That means `data.main` is undefined.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you used loading while waiting for the API data response, and then rendered your component. Additionally, you can include checks to see if the data exists in the object or not. Please try the code below, as it should be helpful.

```
data && data.main && data.main.temp
```

or better way as below

```
data?.main?.temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait and show loading when data fetched then show it.

```js
// App.jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  
  const API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    (async () => {
      let response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=india&appid=${API_KEY}`).then((respond) => respond.json());

      setData(response);
      setLoading(false);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <h1>{loading ? "Please wait!" : data?.main?.temp}</h1>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your data that is being passed on is undefined. You can add a conditional check to verify if  weather  exists before rendering the  WeatherDisp  component. Here is an example:

App.js

```
{weather && Object.keys(weather).length > 0 && <WeatherDisp data={weather} />}
```

WeatherDisp.js

```
const WeatherDisp = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{data && data.main && data.main.temp}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```